# online cdnjs script is not attaching(loading) while page runing on browser

Tags: javascript, html, dom, cdn

In my HTML page i want to load the following CDNjs

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.3/js/tether.min.js"></script>`

but in the browser it loads as follows

GET http://localhost:8080/cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js 404 (Not Found)

Now, my question is how to eliminate that attaching the Domain name(localhost:8080) to load my script properly.
I also tried it as

`<script src="../cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.3/js/tether.min.js"></script>`

or

`<script src="../../cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.3/js/tether.min.js"></script>`
But the result is same.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us the complete HTML source code? Or at least the complete <head> tag ?

Comment: I wonder, do you have a <base href> in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check following line.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.3/js/tether.min.js" async></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the FQDN to CloudFlare.  You are doing a relative path lookup currently.

You should not unclude https: here, use // and the browser wil auto-detect. i.e.

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.3/js/tether.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You would use relative URLs if the scripts was local to your server.  External resources must be loaded by FQDN.

Comment: Still it loading with domain name(localhost:8080/myscriptLink).Problem is not solved.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Check the examples in [tether](http://tether.io/examples/list_of_examples/)
I found [sample](http://tether.io/examples/simple/) here we are using as below, which you can modify to cdnjs link. I recommend to open in incognito mode.

**There are several ways to execute an external script:**

- If async is present: The script is executed asynchronously with the rest of the page (the script will be executed while the page continues the parsing)

example:-

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.3/js/tether.min.js" async></script>
```

- If async is not present and defer is present: The script is executed when the page has finished parsing

example:-

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.3/js/tether.min.js" defer></script>
```

- If neither async or defer is present: The script is fetched and executed immediately, before the browser continues parsing the page

example:-

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.3/js/tether.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use following way to include the cdn file.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.3/js/tether.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You should not unclude https: here, use // and the browser wil auto-detect.  i.e. <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.3/js/tether.min.js"></script>

Comment: but it does not mean that we could not use. To describe HTTPS or HTTP is the best practices as per standards.

Comment: my script is same as what you suggested sir.
but its not working....it is internally attaching https://domainname/mylink
How to avoid this?

Comment: If you visited an HTTP page but force requested an HTTPS page, you will get console errors.

Comment: @Spechal But here is the question of cdnjs.cloudflare is running of Https that is my point only. I think we could end the discussion here

Comment: You would get HTTPS errors in the console loaded from a HTTP page and potentially the certificate validation in the browser address bar.  All I am saying.  You'd need to load everything over SSL to include an SSL resource without console errors.